# Use contextual filter on no results behavior

Tags: 7, views

I'm creating a view where I'd like to use the node ID of the current node seen on the page on the no results behavior. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the PHP input format enabled you can use `arg(1)` in the empty text for the view.

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a content pane and send the argument to panels, and use %1 where you want to use the node title.  Pretty much all my views are content panes now so I can use this and similar functionality.